# Debian "Graphical expert install" mode

Tags: debian, partition, gparted, debian-installer

I made a partitions on a new SSD drive (empty), now I want to install Debian, use netinst ISO CD. I chosed "Graphical expert install" type, which show a series of questions. When installation process come to a **Partition disks** step, there is a lot of options, and what's unclear:

- `"Bootable flag : off/on"` -  should I set it "**On**" for **Boot** partition? Should I **skip** it for the other partitions, or should set it **Off** for the rest partitions?
- `"Format the partition: no keep existing data"` - should I format partitions, even they are empty?
- `Reserved blocks: 5%`  - should I use this option? (SSD disk 60GB but really show 55.80GB available, so I assume that ~7% space already reserved?)
- Should I set/change any flag for Swap partition? Currently it marked "F".

What steps should I make starting with "Partition disks" page? Overall, the Debian installer is unclear at this point and does not make installation easier.

Comment: experts don't use *graphical install*...

Comment: I do!  It looks a lot nicer!  When you have a fully automated network installer and you want to demonstrate it, the graphical install is truly the way to go!  That's why it's supposed to be the default in jessie.  I still have the initrd-console.gz on the pxe config as an option for the weird machines. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a critical moment of the installation, the guide doesn't want to interfere too much because:

- you have chosen *expert*
- you could erase data involuntarily

Exposing all possible options to a *GUI* installer is difficult (*GUI* is always limiting choices).

Finally some recommendations:

- Bootable flag for `boot` partion: on
- Other partitions, bootable flag: off/ skip(=off)
- Format the partitions: yes, formatting also creates a suitable file system (e.g. ext4). Choose `no` only if you are sure that the current format will work.
- Swap: leave the default -- it doesn't matter much imo.

Comment: Thanks for tips. Not sure also for `Reserved blocks: 5%` option.

Comment: You only need this on the `/` partition. This is reserved for space the `root` user, which is located in `/root`. Should you run out of disk space, the `root` user will still be able to write to these reserved blocks. If you have a partition for `/home/`, set this factor to `0%` for the `home` partition.

Comment: For the `"Mount point:"` and `"Mount options:"` In Mount point I should set mount point for every partition?(except swap). And what to specify in `"Mount options"`?

Comment: be careful here, the `mount point` is where your partition is being attached to the root `/`. If you want the partition to be automatically mounted, specify a mount point (yes, `swap` doesn't need one). Also, `mount options` shouldn't be necessary.